# Conditionally tell of `.astro` component is being used as a route or component

Tags: astrojs

Within the AstroJS framework (https://astro.build/) you can have .astro files that are route, you can also import these files into other astro files and use them as components. I've seen an issue that depending on what `Astro.request` properties are called, you're only allow to call them when the file is used as a route. Is it possible to conditionally know if the file is a route or a component?

Answer (score 0):

### Response difference

I found a way how to differentiate the route from the component which is by looking at the response. The reason is that the response is sent at the end of the route frontmatter and before the components frontmatter, that's why the header list is going to have more entries.

Although this is possible, I recommend to differentiate between routes and components by design, such as adding properties with default values not to rely on the response structure. Also the response is not to be used by child components but only by the route, this allows Astro to have an optimized stream response.

reference ( caution section https://docs.astro.build/en/guides/server-side-rendering/#astrorequestheaders)

- response log in route and in component

```json
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(1) { 'content-type' => 'text/html' },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: null
  }
}
{
  status: 200,
  statusText: 'OK',
  headers: HeadersList {
    [Symbol(headers map)]: Map(1) { 'content-type' => 'text/html' },
    [Symbol(headers map sorted)]: Map(1) { 'content-type' => 'text/html' }
  }
}
```

### Clarifications

- talking about routes, assumed mode is SSR
- Not talking about integration API but about SSR components runtime API https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/api-reference/
- It is possible for '.astro' file to be both a component and a route when let's say a `pages/404.astro` is a route but is also used by a component from `pages/[...any].astro`
- That nasty case would not allow to check the path where it is in with `import.meta.url` so it could be in pages even if used as component for another route.

### Test of Request similarity

- route = `[...any].astro`
- component = `pages/404.astro`

in each of them the following log is placed

```js
console.log(Astro.request)
console.log(Astro.request.headers)
console.log(Astro.url)
console.log(Astro.params)
console.log(Astro.props)
```

- the test is performed with a single request call (page load) where the execution goes first through 404.astro when it is imported then through [...].astro when its frontmatter is executed.
- The log is then compared with a diff tool